# How to wrap three images eachtime in bootstrap row class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array of images. I need to wrap three images as a group in a row.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
<div class="row" id="group1"> 
   <img 1>
   <img 2>
   <img 3>
</div>

<div class="row" id="group2"> 
   <img 4>
   <img 5>
   <img 6>
</div>
```

.....and it goes on for the remaining images in the array.

I know how to wrap images, and append `<div class="row" id="group1"><div>` into html.

What I don't know is how to assign three images in a group into row divs which contain an id that's dynamically increased according to the number of images in the array.

For example, the first three images are wrapped inside id="group1".

Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update**

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple /> Upload More Images
</div>

<div class="row">
    <span id="whatup" class="wrapMePlease"></span>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            $("#files").on("change", function (e) {
                var files = e.target.files,
                    filesLength = files.length;
                var count = 0;

                for (var n = 0; n < filesLength; n = n + 3)
                //          Insert a row for 3 image cols
                    $("<div class=\"row\" id=\"addColHere0\"></div>").insertAfter("#whatup");

                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {


                    var f = files[i]
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
                        var file = e.target;

                        // get the last DIV which ID starts with ^= "klon"
                        var $div = $('div[id^="addColHere"]:last');

                        // Read the Number from that DIV's ID (i.e: 3 from "klon3")
                        // And increment that number by 1
                        var num = parseInt($div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
                        var changedId = "#addColHere" + (num - 1);
                        // Clone it and assign the new ID (i.e: from num 4 to ID "klon4")
                        var $klon = $div.clone().prop('id', 'klon' + num);

                        // >>> Append $klon wherever you want

                        //          Insert cols inside row 
                        $(changedId.value).append("<div id=\"breakThis\" class=\" col-sm-4 col-xs-6 toBeRemove\" style=\"padding:0 0px;\">" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-12  camera-style-small\"   align=\"left\" >" +
                            "<img style=\"    width:100%; height:100%; z-index:102;\" class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                            "<span class=\"remove icon-delete_icon create-deleteStyle\"></span>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>");
                        i = i + 1;



                        $(".remove").click(function () {
                            //            $(this).parent(".camera-style-small").remove();
                            $(this).closest(".toBeRemove").remove();
                        });
                    });
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);

                }
            });

        } else {
            alert("Sorry, but your browser doesn't support this function. Please update or try another browser.")
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sticking to your pseudo-code example (to help clarify exactly what you're looking for):

```
let html = '';
let groupVal = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    html += `<div class="row" id="group${groupVal}"><div class="col-xs-12">`;
    groupVal++;
  }
  html += `<img ${i + 1}">`;
  if (i % 3 === 0) { html += `</div></div>`; }
}
...
$(TARGET).append(html);
```

It's a real life example of Fizz Buzz!

- The logic to determine if a new "group div" should be created is handled by the modulo operation
- The length of the array is determined by files.length
- [String interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is used to drop the current running variable into the ever-growing html string

Does this seem to be a step in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

As a fan of AngularJs that I am, let me suggest the use of ng-repeat. However, if you are actually willing to add a dependence to your code, many libraries and frameworks offer the iteration functionality, e.g. React, Vue, Angular 2.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in xs" data-ng-attr-id="group{{$index}}">
    <!--Where x is the object currently in the scope from your array of images, and you may even tweak it a little to create objects that have the src to your images.--> 
   <img 1>
   <img 2>
   <img 3>
</div>
```

I also suggest to add col-??-## after the rows to avoid nasty padding issues.

Comment: While this is a nice answer, what makes you think he's using Angular?

Comment: @Jhecht There's no problem that can't be solved by adding more dependencies!